# How to restart mono web application without restarting apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, mono

Is there any way to restart **ONE** web application in mono without having to restart Apache?

Currently I'm doing a `sudo service apache2 restart` everytime I deploy my .NET web application to mono, but it restarts all my other applications, requiring them **ALL** to get reloaded into memory at next web request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the `mod_mono` control panel.

In `httpd.conf`, add

```
<Location /mono>
  SetHandler mono-ctrl
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

You will need to modify the addresses that can access it in the `Allow from` line.

Reload `httpd` and now you can go to `http://some.website.domain/mono`. You can, among other things, reload all or individual mono applications.

Comment: It depends on the distribution. It's usually somewhere such as `/etc/httpd/conf` or `/etc/apache2`.

Comment: Awesome! That's even better!

Answer (score 3):

The easy way:

`touch web.config`

in the root of your web app (make sure web.config has the right casing).

You can also kill the mod_mono process for the web application you want to restart (`ps auxfww` and try to find the pid, then `kill -9 pid`).

Comment: Very good suggestion.(+1)